# Reading xml nodes using VB script

Tags: vbscript, xml-parsing, doctype

I have an xml file that I want to read using VBScript (Technology limitation). Below is the code and xml file. I am able to read the file if there is no DTD element involved but the code doesn't work for file having DTD and xml-style element.

Code-

```
Dim xmlDoc1:Set xmlDoc1 = CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument")
xmlDoc1.async=False
xmlDoc1.load "C:\ABC.xml"
Dim xmlTCID:Set xmlTCID = xmlDoc1.selectNodes("//*")
For nNodeCount = 0 To xmlTCID.length
MsgBox(xmlTCID(nNodeCount).nodeName)
Next
```

ABC.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE RESULT SYSTEM "Result.dtd"[]>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Result.xsl"?>
<SUMMARY>
<TITLE>Test</TITLE>
</SUMMARY>
<IDS>
    <DATA>
      <NAME>A</NAME>
      <VALUE>PASS</VALUE>
    </DATA>
    <DATA>
      <NAME>B</NAME>
      <VALUE>PASS</VALUE>
    </DATA
    <DATA>
       <NAME>C</NAME>
        <VALUE>FAIL</VALUE>
      </DATA
   </IDS>   
    <IDS>
     <DATA>
       <NAME>A</NAME>
        <VALUE>PASS</VALUE>
     </DATA>
     <DATA>
         <NAME>B</NAME>
         <VALUE>FAIL</VALUE>
      </DATA
  </IDS>
```

Note - If I avoid -

```
<!DOCTYPE RESULT SYSTEM "Result.dtd"[]>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Result.xsl"?>
```

The above code is able to read the nodes but with the above two lines in xml file, it gives the below error -

[image]

Requirement - I need to read the name of last DATA node with FAIL for each IDS node.

Any suggestion as what to do to get the code working even with -

```
<!DOCTYPE RESULT SYSTEM "Result.dtd"[]>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Result.xsl"?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As there are problems with your XML - more than one top level element, miising ">" - setting the [ProhibitDTD Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms762632%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to `False` won't solve all of your tasks.

Comment: thanks for trying to help Ekkehard. I tried this one, but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
xmlDoc.validateOnParse=False
```

worked for me.